# zoom in or out to display the path between two markers (android google maps v2)

Tags: android, path, polyline, markers

I'm sorry for my bad english,

I want to display the path between two markers and do an zoom out or in to display also the origin marker and the destination marker.

Thank you.

```
    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    polyline.isVisible();
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(origin);
    builder.include(destination.getPosition());
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,20));
```

Comment: Include your source and destination to LatLngBounds.Builder and build LatLngBounds which shown both point.

Comment: i have already doing that but that not work LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
  builder.include(position);
  builder.include(mamenu.getPosition());
  LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
  mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,20));

Comment: please add this code to your question so other people may know what you have try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link for display maps and use following code for zooming:
   http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
----
----
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```